# Spam click when mouse button is down AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make an AutoHotKey script that will spam the left mouse button whenever I am holding down on the mouse, but when I release it, it stops spamming left mouse button. I have started, but it isn't working the way I want it to. I am just getting two clicks and then it stops, even when I keep holding down the mouse button. Here is my code:

```
while (true) {
    GetKeyState, OutVar, LButton
    while (OutVar = "D") {
        Send {lbutton}
        GetKeyState, OutVar, LButton
    }
}
```

And [this](https://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse.html) is what I am using to test the mouse clicks.

Comment: Just FYI, searching Google with the name of your post, "Spam click when mouse button is down AutoHotKey",  brings up several items that would have solved your issues. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Send` to change the state of the button interferes with `GetKeyState`. You can solve this by using the `P` mode in `GetKeyState`, which retrieves the physical (real) state of the key.

```
#InstallMouseHook
Loop {
    BtnIsDown := GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
    While (BtnIsDown) {
        Send {LButton}
        BtnIsDown := GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to send the button up event, you can just use this:

```
Loop {
    BtnIsDown := GetKeyState("LButton")
    While (BtnIsDown) {
        Send {LButton Down}
        BtnIsDown := GetKeyState("LButton")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
Loop {
    if GetKeyState("LButton")
        Send {LButton Down}
    else
        Break
}
return
```